# sum of a row's multiple column's value

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get the sum of sub_1, sub_2, sub_3 for every student individually

[image]

Comment: show me database table structure

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdnra.png

does it show the table?

Comment: you should not post code as image.

Comment: thanks for the edit

Comment: Just use `SUM(sub_1, sub_2, sub_3) as value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is mysql:

```
select s_f_name,s_l_name,SUM(sub_1 + sub_2 + sub_3) as total from tablename group by s_f_name,s_l_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT s_id, s_f_name, s_l_name, s_roll_no, s_class, SUM(sub_1 + sub_2 + sub_3) AS sum FROM <table name> GROUP BY s_id
```

Output :

```
s_id   s_f_name   s_l_name   s_roll_no   s_class   sum
1      Mridul     Kumar      1           1         42
2      Manish     Paul       2           1         48
3      Sritima    Baneriee   3           1         57
```

Comment: would you take a look at this question? thanks in advance
https://stackoverflow.com/q/50790423/9857683